# Gradle duplicate dependency in library and project

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

We are working on an application (APP) that uses a local maven dependency library (LIB). LIB uses a custom .jar of OkHttp, and APP also uses OkHttp (not custom).  When we try to build, we get a 'Multiple dex files define X' error, and enabling multiDex gives an error about a duplicate ZipException.  APP is trying to refer to the OkHttp.jar in LIB, when we want it to not do that.  And, well, we can't get it to work.

We've tried placing this in our APP gradle file with no luck:

```
compile(LIB) {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup', module: 'okhttp';
}
```

And, unfortunately, we can't not use LIB. Thoughts? Also, `gradle -q dependencies` does not list any dependencies under LIB, but we know that it uses a `compile file('CUSTOM_OKHTTP')` line in its gradle.

Comment: please provide full `build.gradle` and output with your current error

Comment: provide also pom of LIB.